# My business page on Stack Overflow Jobs has been locked by a private user

Tags: support, developer-story, companies-page

I think I need some support from SO, unless I'm just missing something obvious on my Developer Story page.

On my Developer Story, the company I own helpfully has a link to a page here on SO, but the page appears not to be editable, has a blank avatar named Private User on it, and on my Developer story the URL and logo sections can not be edited.

Did someone else "claim" my business name on SO?

Unrelated, perhaps, I registered my company in Ohio in 2004, but let my original domain name lapse a few years ago.  Currently a company named Domain Protection Company is squatting on my old URL.  I wonder if it's possible to turn over control of the page to me from the anonymous "private user".

Comment: I sorted it out.  The (x) icon on the developer story didn't mean I couldn't edit, apparently, as clicking on it made the field editable.  This is a little confusing from a UI perspective.

Answer (score 3):

The answer for this is to click on the company url or name where they give an input hint on mouse over that appears to indicate the fields are locked. They are also grayed out.  However, clicking unlocks the fields and I was able to both change the URL and upload my logo.